# Electron Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, atom-editor

I've successfully built node.js addon, which works well with Node on Windows. 
Now, I want to create a Windows app using Electron. When loading the module in HTML file, I got the error:

```
var dbr = require('./build/Release/dbr');
```

[image]

Something wrong with **ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js**.
[image]

The issue only occurred on Windows. On Linux and Mac, it worked well.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to rebuild your native Node addon for Electron, [the steps are outlined in the docs](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.37.2/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md#using-native-node-modules).

Comment: I have rebuilt the module for Windows, and it's working now. Could you explain why I don't need to rebuild the module for Linux and Mac? Thanks.

Comment: @yushulx Hi, i did rebuilt using electron rebuild , but still i am facing the same issue, anything i should be careful of while rebuilding

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Electron 2 version and have the same error with another module.

I solved this problem by this advise on Electron page: **To ensure your native dependencies are always matched electron version**, simply add script `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"` to your `package.json`.

And then I changed: `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps && npm run lint:fix"`. Then `npm run postinstall`.