# Electron running SQLlite 3 on Windows - A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

This is similar to this [Electron Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029955/electron-uncaught-error-a-dynamic-link-library-dll-initialization-routine-fai)

```
ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173
        return old.apply(this, arguments)
                   ^

Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\C:\workspace\client\client\desktop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v57
-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\client\client\desktop\node_modules\sqlit
e3\lib\sqlite3.js:4:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\client\client\desktop\node_modules\sqlit
e3\lib\sqlite3.js:190:3)
```

I've tried everything suggested in this post and anything else I can find

I've installed electron-rebuild and added  "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3 -V 1.7"

This is running without errors.

I tried "postinstall": "install-app-deps",

This isn't helping..

Anything else to try?

The files are in there..

[image]

The

Comment: I have this exact problem and I have it half-solved. It works in the packaged installer version now but still getting the same error in the dev version. I'll post an answer when I get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I gave up and used better-sqlite - it's working much better

Comment: It's because it's out of date and doesn't work in any version of node above 6

Comment: That doesn't really make sense considering it works great on Mac / Linux. It is also not an option for me because it is a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up being a mashup of a bunch of different issues on my end. I'll start with the simplest and go from there.

#### Platform

Your error there indicates that it wants `node-v57-win32-x64`, but if you are running from Electron it should be `electron-v2.0-win32-x64` (or `electron-v1.7-win32-x64` if you are using an older version). I ran into this as well because I am running `sqlite3` in a child process. Child processes in Electron are in a full node context and not an Electron (browser or node+browser) context. I fixed this by passing the Electron version from the main browser process (`process.versions.electron`) to the child process via an environment variable and setting it on `process.versions.electron` in the child process.

WARNING: that is a HACK and works because I'm not using anything that expects a full Electron environment in that process. It is literally only to make it find the correct native bindings. A more correct fix would be to look into making `electron-builder` build `node-v57-win32-x64` instead.

Speaking of which, let's create those next.

#### postinstall

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
}
```

This should attempt to rebuild your native dependencies when running `npm install` or `yarn install`. If you have a `project/app` directory, they will be placed in `project/app/node_modules/`. Otherwise they'll go in `project/node_modules`.

#### Transitive Dependency

In my case, `sqlite3` is actually a transitive dependency of another package in my dependency set. While `electron-builder` on Linux/OS X picked these up correctly and showed this during installer creation:

```
• rebuilding native production dependencies platform=linux arch=x64
• rebuilding native dependency name=sqlite3
```

the Windows build showed:

```
• no native production dependencies
```

This was fixed by adding the transitive dependency as a direct dependency. After I did this, the package started to be picked up by electron-builder for compilation and was spitting out errors.

#### Windows Build

To fix those errors:

- Install python (I used the latest 2.7)
- Install [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) and restart
- run your `postinstall` script again

This is the point where I said it was "half-solved" on my end. This *should* be the full solution for basic electron project setups.

#### yarn workspaces

I use the yarn workspaces feature and my project setup is something like this:

```
yarn-workspace-project/
  workspace/
    project/
      web-app/
    project-electron/
      app/
```

For this kind of setup, `yarn install` is generally run in the `yarn-workspace-project` or `yarn-workspace-project/workspace` directory, rather than in each project. This produces a hoisted `node_modules/` directory at `yarn-workspace-project/node_modules`. When creating the packaged version, `electron-builder` grabs the dependencies from that hoisted location and everything runs.

When running my start script in `project-electron`, however, `electron .` had some issues finding the native binding. The package using sqlite3 was installed under `yarn-workspace-project/node_modules`, and was therefore resolving `sqlite3` to `yarn-workspace-project/node_modules/sqlite3`. This definitely exists per the `yarn install`, but the electron bindings got put in `yarn-workspace-project/workspace/project-electron/app/node_modules/sqlite3`.

There are multiple obvious solutions to that, so I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader. The key problem here is that the default bindings that get downloaded (I think? I don't recall them being built) for `node-v57-win32-x64` do not work out of the box for Windows 10 like they do for Linux / OS X, even though the error indicates that they don't exist (which they do).